# What is the time between blinks of the terminal cursor?

Tags: command-line, cursor

What is the time between blinks of the terminal cursor? Perhaps in terms of seconds.

Comment: :) count how many in a 1 min, or record screen if it's too fast.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `gconf-editor` (install with `sudo apt-get install gconf-editor`), then check in `Desktop->gnome->interface : cursor_blink_time` entry (express in milliseconds).

[image]

or using commandline:

```
gconftool --get /desktop/gnome/interface/cursor_blink_time
```

Answer (score 4):

To get the time in milliseconds between blinks of the gnome-terminal cursor (default is 1200), you can use the following command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-time
```

To set the time to another value, let say 2400 for example, you can use:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-blink-time 2400
```

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the terminal emulator you are using. @giradengo showed you what (presumably) is the default for `gnome-terminal`. In `xterm`, you can control this with the `-bcf` and `-bcn` flags:

```
   -bcf milliseconds
           set the amount of time text cursor is off when blinking via the
           cursorOffTime resource.

   -bcn milliseconds
           set the amount of time text cursor is on when blinking via  the
           cursorOffTime resource.
```

In general, the details will always depend on your terminal emulator, some (such as `terminator`) don't seem to support blinking at akk while others let you customize it.